# Why PHP and MYSQL so popular?

Tags: php, mysql

hey guy I have a question which is why php and mysql so popular together?

Comment: This isn't a programming related question and thus doesn't belong here.

Comment: Because they're free

Comment: they are better than the alternative.

Comment: @see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110797/why-is-php-so-frequently-used-on-web-servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the answer is mySQL is a free RDBMS, and PHP has built-in support for it.